# Issues with String to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

My dateFromString is not working and i'm not sure why

```
NSString *purchase = @"2011-09-30 17:47:57";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:purchase];
```

date is 'invalid CFStringRef'

See anything i might be overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the format

"hh" means Hour [1-12].

"HH" means Hour [0-23].

See [UTS Date Field Symbol Table](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the date format specifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the hours in the formatter to capitals, i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

I'm not sure if that will solve your error, but that is the correct way to parse a 24 hour time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *purchase = @"2011-09-30 17:47:57";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:purchase];
```

[Date Formatters Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) -  `HH` is used for 24 hour times, `hh` for 12 hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that "date" is not accepted as an NSString by another function, that's because it's not a string, it's an NSDate.

(Where, precisely, are you getting the error message, and what is the full text?)